# How to read JSON key values as a data column in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the below sample JSON:

```
{
   "Id1": {
      "name": "Item1.jpg",
      "Status": "Approved"
   },
   "Id2": {
      "name": "Item2.jpg",
      "Status": "Approved"
   }
}
```

and I am trying to get the following output:

```
_key    name        Status
Id1     Item1.jpg   Approved
Id2     Item2.jpg   Approved
```

Is there any way I can achieve this in Snowflake using SQL?

Answer (score 6):

You should use Snowflake's VARIANT data type in any column holding JSON data. Let's break this down step by step:

```
create temporary table FOO(v variant); -- Temp table to hold the JSON. Often you'll see a variant column simply called "V"

-- Insert into the variant column. Parse the JSON because variants don't hold string types. They hold semi-structured types.
insert into FOO select parse_json('{"Id1": {"name": "Item1.jpg", "Status": "Approved"}, "Id2": {"name": "Item2.jpg", "Status": "Approved"}}');

-- See how it looks in its raw state
select * from FOO;

-- Flatten the top-level JSON. The flatten function breaks down the JSON into several usable columns
select * from foo, lateral flatten(input => (foo.v)) ;

-- Now traverse the JSON using the column name and : to get to the property you want. Cast to string using ::string.
-- If you must have exact case on your column names, you need to double quote them.
select  KEY                     as "_key",
        VALUE:name::string      as "name",
        VALUE:Status::string    as "Status"
from FOO, lateral flatten(input => (FOO.V)) ;
```

Comment: Thanks, I did found that FLATTEN function was doing what I needed. But your answers made my code better.

Comment: Can we do the same without specifying the column, i.e, by parsing the column name from json directly ?

Comment: Maybe, but I'm not entirely clear on the requirement. It's probably worth posting as a new question to have some room to provide details and code samples.